# Magento Search returns All Products

Tags: php, mysql, search, magento

I have set up a website (www.autobodypartsnow.com) and the search function has gone haywire.  Whenever you search for anything, it returns every product in the system making it useless.  I have fiddled around with it with no prevail.

I have done the Like and FullText thing in the Configuration - nothing.

I have reset the Search and FS cache.

I have actually gone in the product attributes and disabled all the attributes from being searchable (just to see) and Rebuilt the Search Cache, cleared the FS cache and it still does the same thing - which tells me that something it pretty wrong.

Any Ideas?  Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you be specific which plugin did this? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been an un-updated plugin, the update fixed the issue.