# Magento search always return the same products

Tags: search, magento-1.7

My magento (1.7) search always returns the same 15 products, whatever I search for.

This is obviously an index / cache issue, so I am looking for answers about how to debug where the search results are coming from.

I have `rm -rf var/cache` and disabled the cache, and re-indexed everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11413620/347180 fixes the problem.

In my `local.xml` I had:

```
<remove name="catalogsearch.leftnav" />
```

Which is required for the search functionality.

Comment: This might also be seen if you have removed that node in another way, such as 

  <catalogsearch_result_index>
    ...
    <reference name="root">
      <remove name="left" />

Answer (score 3):

in catalogserach.xml...following code should not removed

```
<block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch" after="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added in catalogsearch.xml the folowwing line between   and

```
<block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch" after="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

And now search results are showing ok.